# Performance loss in numba compiled logic comparison

Tags: python, performance, compiler-construction, numba

What could be a reason for performance degradation in the following numba compiled function for logic comparison:

```
from numba import njit

t = (True, 'and_', False)

#@njit(boolean(boolean, unicode_type, boolean))    
@njit
def f(a,b,c):
    if b == 'and_':
        out = a&c
    elif b == 'or_':
        out = a|c
    return out
x = f(*t)
%timeit f(*t)
#1.78 µs ± 9.52 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

---

```
%timeit f.py_func(*t)
#108 ns ± 0.0042 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

To test this at scale as suggested in the answer:

```
x = np.random.choice([True,False], 1000000)
y = np.random.choice(["and_","or_"], 1000000)
z = np.random.choice([False, True], 1000000)

#using jit compiled f
def f2(x,y,z):
    L = x.shape[0]
    out = np.empty(L)
    for i in range(L):
        out[i] = f(x[i],y[i],z[i])
    return out

%timeit f2(x,y,z)
#2.79 s ± 86.4 ms per loop
```

---

```
#using pure Python f
def f3(x,y,z):
    L = x.shape[0]
    out = np.empty(L)
    for i in range(L):
        out[i] = f.py_func(x[i],y[i],z[i])
    return out

%timeit f3(x,y,z)
#572 ms ± 24.3 ms per
```

Am I missing something and if there a way to compile "fast" version, because this is a going to be part of a loop executed ~ 1e6 times.

Comment: 1. You can always implement in c and call a dll. 2. I would tokenize "and_" and "or_" beforehand (maybe this can be vectorized), and call a correct function  based on the token, thus skipping the `if-elif` statement.

Comment: This sounds like a simple version of a compiler. I stand behind the suggestion to first tokenize, and once you have tokenized code, to do operations per token, when the token type is known. If you have for example a "And" token, and a "Or" token, both with `.op()` method, you will be able to first tokenize and then `.op()` which will never do the `if-else`. This is a 2-pass algorithm.

Comment: If this has to be a single-pass algorithm, I believe it can be done with the help of some kind of look-ahead. Anyway, if this is very performance-demanding, save yourself the headaches, and write it in c or c++, only calling from Python

Comment: Maps [don't work](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/7023). Both versions have `if/else`.

Comment: Did you try to define an inheritence structure, something like `BaseOperator(Object), def op(*args)`, `And(BaseOperator)` `Or(BaseOperator)`? Then the static type is defined.

Comment: I also have to state that the code examples are not readable at best. It can do a lot for the question's sake to give meaningful names to variables. It is really hard to understand what is `aa`, `bb`, `cc`, `dd`, `X` and so on as an outsider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working at a *too small granularity*. Numba is not designed for that. Almost all the execution time you see comes from the **overhead** of wrapping/unwrapping parameters, type checks, Python function wrapping, reference counting, etc. Moreover the benefit of using Numba is very small here since Numba barely optimizes unicode string operations.

One way to check this hypothesis is to just execute the following trivial function:

```py
@njit
def f(a,b,c):
    return a
x = f(True, 'and_', False)
%timeit f(True, 'and_', False)
```

Both the trivial function and the original version takes 1.34 µs on my machine.

Additionally, you can *disassemble* the Numba function to see how much instructions are executed to perform just one call and understand deeply where the overheads are coming from.

If you want Numba to be useful, you need to **add more work** in the compiled function, possibly by *working directly on arrays/lists*. If this is not possible because of the dynamic nature of the input type, then Numpy may not be the right tool for this here. You could try to rework a bit your code and use *PyPy* instead. *Writing a native C/C++ module* may help a bit but most of the time will be spend in manipulating dynamic objects and unicode string as well as doing type introspection, unless you rewrite the whole code.

---

**UPDATE**

The above overhead is only paid when transitioning from Python types to Numba (and the other way around). You can see that with the following benchmark:

```py
@njit
def f(a,b,c):
    if b == 'and_':
        out = a&c
    elif b == 'or_':
        out = a|c
    return out
@jit
def manyCalls(a, b, c):
    res = True
    for i in range(1_000_000):
        res ^= f(a, b, c ^ res)
    return res

t = (True, 'and_', False)
x = manyCalls(*t)
%timeit manyCalls(*t)
```

Calling `manyCalls` takes 3.62 ms on my machine. This means each call to `f` takes 3.6 ns in average (16 cycles). This means the overhead is paid only once (when `manyCalls` is called).

Comment: Thanks for your time! It's absolutely no doubt numba will shine on lengthy vectorized loops. The question is how to properly compile logic parser that will be fed into the loop, and is it possible to recover 10x performance loss (and in the final analysis will numba provide net gain).

Comment: The problem is not really the 10x performance loss. You can easily remove it if the parsing code is JITed too. The main problem is if Numba can actually improve the performance of the parsing code and I am not sure this is possible, mainly because of the input itself: dynamic types and recursion are really bad for Numba. The only case where Numba can help here is if the expression `t` is the same for many different `X`. In that case, you can generate a compiled function specifically for a given `t`. Otherwise, my advice is to use another tool or rewrite your parser in C/C++.

Comment: I am not after performance improvement on a logic of 10 statements. 10x slowdown multiplied by 1e6 alarms me.

Comment: You can see the Numba overhead just as a fixed transition cost between CPython and Numba to pay. AFAIK, this cost should not be paid for calling (njitted) Numba function when the caller is a (njitted) Numba function too. `1.34 µs * 1e6 = 1.34 s` is a problem, but paying 1.34 µs once should be fine. So this is why the `_eval` function should use Numba as well as possibly the code calling `_eval` too.

Comment: `_eval` must be njitted. It's not at the time due to `isinstance` but it would. Concerning `The problem is not really the 10x performance loss. You can easily remove it if the parsing code is JITed too.` It's already jitted. And it shows 10x slowdown. If you can prove this overhead will magically disappear on larger loops -- dispelling my concerns -- it will be nice.

Comment: I just added a benchmark to show the overhead is paid only once (it does not "magically disappear", but is negligible as long as the work is big enough, which is the case here)

Comment: Makes more sense now. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my question too, with both updates telling me: sending data to and fro between Pyhton  and numba compiled code is waste of time.